# Trying to get two websites on one server and ip

Tags: server, apache2

Ok I've been looking around for a while and I'm pretty sure I have the virtualhost file configured properly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent http://www.example.com/ /

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ScriptAlias /cgi/ /var/www/html/cgi-bin/

<Directory /var/www/html/cgi-bin/>
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.net
Redirect permanent http://www.example.net/ /

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.com
Redirect permanent http://www.test.com/ /

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is one .conf file. Hopefully I can get 3 sites working on one ip address. I've looked around, and everything says that this should be working, but it's not. Typing in any of the domain names in on a browser only ever reveals one website, no matter what the DocumentRoot is set to.

Is there some other setting I should no about. Should I have multiple .conf files enabled. Should I work off of different ports.

Why is this not working.

Comment: Did you reload the configurations after adding the other sites?

Comment: yes. I have again just to make sure

Comment: could it be something to do with the redirects

Comment: also, my error log show that someone did manage to log onto the other site, they just caused an error as the file they requested wasn't there, it was a file for the other site. Could it be working some of the time

Comment: How are you yourself testing?  With curl, or with a web browser?

Comment: i'm testing on my laptop with a browser

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? When something connects to the single IP address,  is it supposed to send something like "I want www.test.com"? That is not how it works. Use `wireshark` to watch the packets and you will see that there is no difference between packets sent to `www.example.net` (which resolves to the Single IP) and those sent to `www.test.com` (which also resolves to the single IP).

Comment: Erase your browser cache after each test.  Cached lookups and cached data being returned are the bane of existence.

Comment: 'not working' I mean that all traffic gets sent to example.com folder. I asked a question on server fault aswell. Someone told me it was to do with the redirects. So I removed them, but still all traffic gets sent to default or example.com file folder. I really need to get this working soon. I've got  a mountain of things to do.

Comment: do i need to set up a name server or something

Answer (score -1):

First of all I got rid of the redirects as they were irrelevant.

Now I use ServerAlias
I also use DirectoryIndex
I set them up in different virtual hosts on same port using wildcard entry

Enabled all three and now it works.

Comment: I need help with this @Tom Albanese